# Is there a formula, which gives a relation to quark masses?

Tags: mass, standard-model, quarks

There're a plenty of formulas giving a relation to lepton masses - Koide formula, Brannen's extension and Baruta's formula. But is there a formula, which gives relation between quark masses?

P.S. Yes, I know, that all of the formulas above might be a coincidence

Comment: It is always better to cite and link to specific sources, even if you think the experts who can answer your question don't need them. In this case, giving links to Koide, Brannen's, and Baruta's formulas will increase the chance you will get a response.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koide_formula#Similar_formulae

Comment: The WP article references (misbegotten) extensions of Koide to quarks, but I suspect no other formulas. I'm not sure why numerology should be friendlier  to leptons than to quarks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In mainstream physics, speculative relations among quark masses pertain, not to their observed values, but to the extrapolated value of their yukawa coupling (coupling to the Higgs) at grand unification energies. A paradigmatic example of this would be [the Georgi-Jarlskog mass relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georgi%E2%80%93Jarlskog_mass_relation). In general, the expectation is that any exact relations of significance exist only at unification scales, but only qualitative echoes would remain at lower energies, such as third-generation masses being greater than the first two generations. Any exact relationship among low-energy masses is considered a coincidence, which is why the relationships you mention have only attracted marginal attention.

Among the lepton formulas, Koide's is the best known, and he and his collaborators in Japan have done by far the most work to embed it within recognizable frameworks of quantum field theory. That includes some explanation of how the quark masses fit into a larger picture. Of these, I find [a 2017 paper by Koide and Nishiura](https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.06287) the most interesting. Some of the new parameters on page 12 are close to being integers, and might have an explanation in grand unification.

As Cosmas Zachos points out, there have also been extensions of the Koide formula to the quarks, but outside any field-theoretic framework. One class of these is based on Carl Brannen's refinement of the Koide formula, to exhibit dependence on a new parameter, an angle. This works exactly for the charged leptons, and people have sought similar parameters for the quark families, but there the fit is no longer exact. Piotr Zenczykowski gets a better fit using "pseudo-masses" associated with the flavor eigenstates of the quarks, rather than the usual mass eigenstates. I believe this idea is due to François Goffinet; see [Zenczykowski's paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.4143) for the literature on both.

If we are to judge such formulas without worrying too much about how to actually produce them, then by far the best (in my opinion) is [Alejandro Rivero's descent relation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.7232), which ties together all six quarks in a series of intertwined Koide triples. It looks vaguely like a cascade of radiatively generated masses ([example](https://inspirehep.net/literature/26068)), but no one knows how to implement such a cascade with the peculiar alternating structure that Rivero unearthed.

As a reality check, I would return to my opening remarks: in mainstream physics, which is to say, in the lines of research based on ideas that have actually worked, people look for formulas that would be exact only at high energies (e.g. look for "zero textures" or "the democratic matrix"; the latter has featured in some of Koide's work too). There *are* phenomena which can produce special low-energy values (e.g. existence of an "infrared fixed point"), but one doesn't particularly expect them to look like any of these quark mass formulas. It would be an incredible breakthrough if any of them could be derived from an actual field theory.